# If I selected (highlight) a feature or points would I be able to color that feature as as it is being highlighted?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, point, color

[image: black dots are highlighted]

The points on purple and lightgreen area I want to maintain them reds. The points outside that I want to color them yellow not just the highlighted ones. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select all the features you want to have a different color.
2. Use the Field Calculator to add a new field. Check the box for "selected features only". Fill in a field name, and fill in a value in the expression area (in my example below, I called the field "category" and filled it with the value `1`.

   [image]

   Now the point layer has a new field called "category". The selected points have the value `1` in this field. The other points have `null` in the field.
3. Set up a categorized style based on the "category" field:

   - Open the Layer Styling panel.
   - Choose "categorized" from the first dropdown menu (instead of "single symbol").
   - Choose the field "category" from the Column dropdown menu.
   - Click the Classify button.

   [image]
4. Now the points you selected in step 1 are all one random color, and the other points are a different random color. Change the colors for each category to the color you want.

Comment: ok, I've tried it but, the ones in red are gone, I want the points that are in red to stay in the map with the ones that I've color changed.

Comment: Those points should now have the symbol of the catchall category (that's the category with no specified value). In my example it's blue, but yours will be a different color because the colors are chosen randomly. You'll have to change the symbology back to red.

Comment: I found a way around it, thank you. I did what you've shown here and it worked, then I duplicated the shapefile, positioned the copy on top and it showed only the ones i highlighted with a different color but also showing the original points in yellow. Thanks!